# How to mute Ajax 404 Errors?

Tags: ajax, image, http-status-code-404

My script attempts to load an image URL with ajax. If they image is not found ajax throws an 404 error. The script then loads a fallback image. This is intended, but I don't like that the browser console shows the 404 error of the image that was not found. Is that a way to mute the error? Or am I approaching this the wrong way?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: try_img_url,
    success: function(response){

    //if finds the image, use it.
    },
    error: function(response){

          //if does not find the image, use fall back image.

    }
});
```

My other idea, was to check if the image url exists before making the ajax call, that way I would not have to make the call at all if the image doesn't exist. However, I am not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is possible with JS but I would approach this by adding a small PHP script like eg `getimage.php` then use that to check if the file exists.

PHP:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['image']) && is_file($_GET['image'])) {
    echo sprintf("<img src='%s' />", $_GET['image']);
} else {
    echo "<img src='fallback.jpg' />";
}
?>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
    $.get('getimage.php', function (data) { 
        $("body").html($("body").html() + data);
    });
});
```